# Left-aligned table caption in sphinx

Tags: css, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

Is there a way to left-align table captions in Sphinx output (using sphinx_rtd_theme)?

Custom css is included in conf.py:

```
def setup(app):
    app.add_stylesheet('_static/custom.css')
```

This is working:

```
.wy-nav-content {
     max-width: none;
 }
```

Neither of these work:

```
.caption {
     align:left
 }
```

or

```
.caption-text {
     align:left
 }
```

Is it possible via custom css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use correct CSS syntax for aligning text:

```
.caption-text {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @steve-piercy. I tried this, but there is no effect on output. It appears some other css/ script has overriding effect. I'm unable to identify it.

Comment: Did you try editing this to reflect any custom CSS? https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme/blob/b82993dfdb5559b40a0ab4839015bc6c093b6ddf/docs/conf.py#L143

Comment: It exists and is uncommented `html_static_path = ['_static']`. As I mentioned `wy-nav-content` setting worked from same css.

Answer (score 0):

The correct CSS selector for a code-block caption is `.rst-content .code-block-caption`:

```
.rst-content .code-block-caption  {
    text-align: left;
}
```